# What is a correct/polite way to inherit from an abandoned open-source project for a new open-source project?

Tags: project-management, open-source

My team just tried to contact some guys from an old open source project hosted on code.google.com. We told them that we'd like to join their project and commit to it — at least to some branch of it — but no one responded to us. We tried everyone, owners and committers; no one was in any way active, and no one replied.

But we have some code to commit and we really would love to continue work on that project. So we need to create a new project. We came up with a name for it which is close to but not a duplicate of the name of the project we want to inherit from. How should we do our first commit, and what should the commit message be? Should we just copy their code to our repository with a comment like "we inherited this code, we found it here under such and such a license ... now we're upgrading it to this more/less strict license ..."? Or should we just use their code as our first commit, with updates saying "we inherited from ... we made such and such changes ..."?

Comment: Unless you get permission from the original project, depending on the original licence you likely won't be able to make it a less strict licence. If it's a licence permissive enough to allow that then there probably isn't much need to move to an even more permissive licence.

Answer (score 13):

Ideally you would fork it on Google Code, which would keep all the old history. I don't know if this is explicitly supported on Google Code, but if the old project is using git as it's version control, you can do it manually by cloning the old project to a local directory, modifying the `origin` remote to point to your new repository, then pushing your local copy.

I'm sure a similar method can be used with subversion (`svnsync` perhaps?) but I have no practical experience with subversion so I can't comment there.

Comment: google code supports Mercurial, but not git. For mercurial the procedure is very similar though, just modify the `default` alias in `.hg\hgrc`.

Comment: @Wim thanks for the info. I really haven't used Google Code much at all, just providing as much info about what I know as possible.

Answer (score 8):

The crucial thing is whether the license of the original code and what it allows you to do.  One thing you should be very careful about is to change the license since you simply may not be allowed to do so - remember you do not have copyright.

But, assuming that all is in perfect order then the initial commit message could be "Imported 2011-02-25 from http://.... version X.Y.Z", as well as a prominent explanation in the README.txt file.

Be very clear about what you have done, and if at all possible write your code using the original code as a library.  This makes it much easier to separate concerns.

Answer (score 8):

This is actually a [google code FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/FAQ#Hosting_Your_Open_Source_Project_on_Google_Code), see "What should I do if I wish to take over a project that appears abandoned by its owners?".

Apparently you can take over abandoned projects by asking Google nicely.

Answer (score 4):

If you contacted the old project then I don't think they can complain, just be open and clear about what you're doing and don't take credit for others' work. I'd probably try to explain the situation both on your web site and in the first commit message. It'd also be polite to be sure the initial code import is *exactly* the same as the previous project, so all changes are in the commit logs.

As others have said, you can only change the license to a compatible one, and you CANNOT change the copyright owners, even if you change the license. It's important to keep all the existing copyright owners' names on there and in all files they worked on.

Answer (score 1):

Create a fork, in the initial commit and readme add something like

> For of *project name* because *of reasons*. Original http://example.com/project

for an example see https://github.com/timtadh/gobuild-fork

Answer (score 1):

I found Wim Coenen's [link to the Google Code FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/FAQ#Hosting_Your_Open_Source_Project_on_Google_Code) helpful. I just searched and sourceforge also has [a policy for taking over abandoned projects](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Abandoned%20Project%20Takeovers)

It seems that Sourceforge requires the current administrators to respond.  I think I like the idea that if I get hit by a bus, then Google will hand over my project for me.  I think I'm leaning toward Google code for this reason.